# node paymentMethods.list equivalent in @stripe/react-stripe-js

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve all payment methods listed for a customer in stripe using react. I have access to publishable key and client secret.

But, I am unable to find a method to retrieve the payment methods (similar to the one in node - stripe.paymentMethods.list or PaymentMethodsRetrievalListener in Android).

Any help, much appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such a method unfortunately!

The backend API for listing PaymentMethods (https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list)  generally requires a secret key(which is what stripe-node uses), not something you can use in a React frontend.

The mobile SDKs like Android use the ephemeral key they get from your backend (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#add-server-endpoint) to call the same API — it's technically possible to do this yourself on the web too but it's not documented in any way so it's not really a good option.

Overall you would normally just have your frontend call your backend, your backend(written in e.g. Node and using your secret API key) can call https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list  and return the information the frontend is looking for.